# C# Winform get data from API every 10 seconds and save in folder

Tags: c#, winforms, thread-safety, task, threadpool

I want send POST data to API and receive data every 10 seconds. Next I want parse received data to json and save to file. I don't want block UI. Method will work 24hrs.

This is C# Winforms program to download data from API and save it on local disc.

```
            printerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InvokeMethod))
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            printerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            printerThread.Start();
```

I expect lightweight solution :)

Comment: Your code doesn't really reflect your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look how to ask a proper question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow . We don't write your code.

Comment: I advised to you use background worker to prevent block UI thread. Also you can use timer to scheduled your actions. Call your api in bgworker on every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can actually be divided into three parts
1. Post every 10s => `Timer` + `WebClient`
2. Get data, convert to JSON then save to file => `JsonConvert` + `File.WriteAllText()`
3. Don't block UI(and I assume, the request thread itself) => `async await`

You didn't include the data structure but I suppose you can check out JsonConvert yourself, a quick example for the rest.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(async (state) =>
{
    string feedback = "";
    try
    {
        var uriOfAPI = new Uri("http://httpbin.org/post");
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
            feedback = await webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(uriOfAPI, "POST", "whatever the input should be");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // how you are going to handle when API malfunction
    }

    // feedback convert to json(in this example, it already is)

    File.WriteAllText(@".\output.txt", feedback);

}, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```